# Why isn't this if block being executed

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have the following function within my code to read a users profile picture from a firebase database.

```
func setupProfile() {
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 64
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    dbref.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let user = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        let username = user?["username"] as! String?
        let url = user?["profileImage"] as? String!
        if url == nil {
            let pic = UIImage(named: "placeholderImage")
            self.profileImageView.image = pic
            dbref.removeAllObservers()
            return
        }

        self.usernameLabel.text = "@" + username!
        //self.profileImageView.downloadImage(from: url!)
    })
    dbref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

But when the profileImage field is empty it still isn't executing the code inside the

```
if url == nil
```

block executing, I'm aware that observeSingleEvent creates a listener that looks for changes in the data but I thought it would execute all of the code in 'with' closure which would mean hitting the if statement. What am I missing here, why isn't this code executing all the rest of the code is.

Comment: you are calling  `dbref.removeAllObservers()` right after adding the observer

Comment: @ReinierMelian even if I remove that line, I still get the same same behaviour.

Comment: When you say empty what you mean, `""` empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove ! from the end of line:

```
let url = user?["profileImage"] as? String
```

Comment: See that's what I thought, but I just tried putting a print statement in again and I've had no luck the block just isn't executing. I've checked the debugger too and url definitely contains nil.

Comment: remove ! from the end of line : `let url = user?["profileImage"] as? String`